# How to fight an unemployment tax bill that I do not owe in NY?

Tags: united-states, taxes, fraud, new-york, unemployment

Back in the summer I received a tax bill saying I owe money for unemployment, but I do not as I never filed it. It's most likely fraud claim under my name or company.

Below are the redacted documents showing they corrected my 1099G, but I still got a bill for it. On the back of that bill it says I can fight it with a "Conciliation conference" or "Division of Tax Appeals". What should I do? or is there some place I can just call to make this resolved?

I downloaded and filled this 1099g review form:

https://dol.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2021/12/lo1099rq_12-21.pdf

And in Nov I got an updated 1099G, which shows updated copy with $0.

[image]

Then in DEC 2022, i receive a letter saying I owe money:

[image]

When I try to filr for the "Conciliation conference" on the my.ny.gov website, i get hit with these options. Picking disagree other reasons just hits you back to the main page. I'm not sure what to do next.

[image]

Comment: There's a phone number on the notice - had you tried it? Did the bill and the corrected 1099-G come together or separately? It could just be the right hand doesn't know what the left is doing

Comment: The only phone number is the pay the bill. if you want to fight it, you have to fill out some "conciliation conference" thing on their website which isn't clear at all.

Comment: Are you the employee or the company owner?

Answer (score 42):

I actually called the number on the notice: 518-599-6837 -- It's quite a number of prompts, but they reps picked up pretty fast and was informative. They let me know that this has been happening very frequently in the past year with stolen identity unemployment fraud. They told me no need to file for the "disagree" with the statement option.

The way to deal with this fraud is to send your TAX bill statement to:

```
NYS Assessment Receivables
PO BOX 4128
Binghamton, NY 13902
```

Yes its PO BOX 4128, and not 4127 as stated on the letter. The only way to to get PO BOX 4128 was by calling in and the representative telling me to send to this and **NOT 4127**. Someone can double confirm by calling in again.

Send along with a COPY of the updated 1099G corrected copy showing $0 of unemployment.

Also you should file a DTF-275 form to report identity theft so they can monitor your tax account more carefully.

Comment: Send a copy of your TAX bill statement, surely ?  Or keep a copy.

Comment: Note that the listed PO Box here is listed as 4128 in this answer, but 4127 on the photo provided.

Comment: yes the rep told me to send to PO BOX 4128 and NOT 4127... We can only get this info from calling in apparently. It doesn't state it anywhere on the web.

Comment: I've been wondering if there ever been someone scamming on this site by using a wrong answer to a question, particularly when giving addresses, etc.